# SQL provide data with predefined rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for an elegant way, to provide data, with rules regard to contents.

Let´s assume the following:
I want to calculate the discount for customers. I have Customer-Categories, "HappyHours" and the discount.

I have 9 different categories, and for each category there are 3 different Happy-Hour-Times. The discount depends on a combination of category and time. The values won´t change frequently, so I am looking for a "constant" way to solve this issue.

Example:

1. categoryPremium && timeOne equals 20% discount
2. categoryPremium && timeTwo equals 22% discount
3. categoryPremium && timeThree equals 30% discount
4. categoryRegular && timeOne equals 10% discount
5. categoryRegular && timeTwo equals 15% discount

and so on...

This is for an application, and the discount is required at each execution. So it would be really nice to find a way, which is clean and fast.

I thought of two possibilities:

1. A table, with composite primary key (category and happyHour) filled once manually
2. A hard coded assignment-function (similar to [the number of matches between two rows mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380180/the-number-of-matches-between-two-rows-mysql/28430898#28430898))

What do you think? Is there a way which is more dynamic?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh: sql-server. Sorry. I think this problem can be solved either logically or technically. I thought, that for the logical way the technology isn´t that important and I wanted to include people with mysql backround

Comment: If that is the wrong way, I´ll do it differently next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have a reference table, with columns such as:

- Category
- HappyHourTime
- Premium

Then you can look up the values using the reference table.  Something like:

```
select t.*, r.premium
from t join
     reference r
     on t.category = r.category and t.happyhourtime = r.happyhourtime;
```

This is similar to your first choice.  However, I would have a synthetic identity primary key and have the other two column have a unique constraint.  Also, you might consider turning this into a slowly changing dimension (with an effective and end date), so you can keep track of changes over time.

Comment: Thx!! Yes, thought that can be one way. The "slowly-changing-dimension" thing sounds very interesting! For this part it will be far to much, but I´ll keep this in mind, there will be lots of situations where this can help a lot! The unique-constraints are (from my perspective) not helpful here. Both, category and happyHour, will contain the same values twice or more...

Comment: that was the reason for my composite-pk-idea.. Because the combination of both, in conjunction to the discount, is unique

Comment: @Joshit . . . You misunderstand.  The unique constraint is on the pair.  I (almost) always use synthetic primary keys.  Unique constraints enforce rules on other columns.

Comment: Ahh.. alright!! Thx for explaning it again! Did not know that this is possible. I´ll prefer the synthetic key too.. But to your reference-table again: I´ve seen now, that you called one column "premium". That was one of my categories..?

Answer (score 1):

From a SQL server perspective, the neatest thing to do is create a table with three columns as per your 1st suggestion (Category, Time, Discount).  You then have two options for your application.  If it were a .net app you could perform a simple select using your category and time values as variables passed through to return the result set.

Or, if you want less SQL code in your app, you could create the table as above and select from a  scalar-valued function created as such:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Discount]  (@Category Varchar(50), @HappyHour TIME)
RETURNS  DECIMAL(8,2)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @Discount DECIMAL(8,2) = (
    SELECT 
    Discount 
    FROM dbo.HappyHourDiscount
    WHERE Category <= @Category
        AND HappyHour = @HappyHour
    )

    RETURN(@Discount)
END
```

Passing the parameters for the function via your app.

Comment: First: thanks for support!
I want to put the discount-value to another table/view and consume this with my application. After joining data from different sources I´ll get the needed parameters (category, happyHour). With these parameters I´ll be able to determine the discount.
I don´t want any SQL-Code in my App. I think the data-transfer will be done with EF...

Comment: But the information is held on the sql db, so you will need to query the database somehow via your app.  Using the function, your SQL in the app would literally look like `SELECT database.dbo.fn_Discount(@Category,@HappyHour)` and you would be able to add the parameters via your application code (e.g. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category",categoryVariable`) in c#.  Otherwise, you are probably looking at some kind of LINQ query again for c#, or you are otherwise looking at hardcoding the values into your app (not recommended).

Comment: You´re right somehow, but thats not my problem here. If I choose your idea, I will execute the function from a stored procedure. I´m trying to get my data in needed condition before accessing the database with my tool. However it turns out, that a function will be a possibility.

Comment: OK, well I think you need to provide more information as to your disparate data sources.  If they are fragmented across different servers, then you need some form of ETL.  If they are on the same server, then you can still create a view of those sources for what you need and run the function off the view.

There is no requirement from an SQL Server perspective to run the function via a stored procedure, it can be selected in its own right.

Comment: If I wanted to use C# (or code in general), I had many ideas to solve this problem. But I want to solve it with SQL. How I´ll access the data is not the problem...